# Многоуровневое меню телеграмм бот на java

Tags: java, telegram-bot

Хочу сделать чтобы при нажатии на кнопку в меню, появлялись новые кнопки(подменю). Не могу это релизовать. То, что пробовал - не помогло. Ниже прикреплю код.

```
public void setButtons(SendMessage sendMessage){
    // Создаем клавиуатуру
    ReplyKeyboardMarkup replyKeyboardMarkup = new ReplyKeyboardMarkup();
    sendMessage.setReplyMarkup(replyKeyboardMarkup);
    replyKeyboardMarkup.setSelective(true);
    replyKeyboardMarkup.setResizeKeyboard(true);
    replyKeyboardMarkup.setOneTimeKeyboard(false);
    // Создаем список строк клавиатуры
    List<KeyboardRow> keyboard = new ArrayList<>();
    // Первая строчка клавиатуры
    KeyboardRow keyboardFirstRow = new KeyboardRow();
    // Добавляем кнопки в первую строчку клавиатуры
    keyboardFirstRow.add("Кнопка 1");
    keyboardFirstRow.add("Кнопка 2");
    // Добавляем все строчки клавиатуры в список
    keyboard.add(keyboardFirstRow);
    // и устанваливаем этот список нашей клавиатуре
    replyKeyboardMarkup.setKeyboard(keyboard);

    if(sendMessage.equals("Кнопка 1")){
        keyboard.clear();
        keyboardFirstRow.clear();
        keyboardFirstRow.add("Новая кмд 2");
        keyboard.add(keyboardFirstRow);
        replyKeyboardMarkup.setKeyboard(keyboard);
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Для этого необходимо создать новую клавиатуру setButtonsNew() и в условие вставить эту клавиатуру
`if(sendMessage.equals("Кнопка 1")){ setButtonsNew(){} }`